# chrome dev tools の Network タブの歯車アイコンは何を表す？

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

chrome dev tools で[gatsby.js の公式サイト](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/)をみていたところ、いくつかのリソースに歯車マークが付与されているのを見つけました。

**Chrome Dev Tools の Network 画面**

[image: chrome dev tool の network 画面]

#### 質問

この歯車は何を表していますか？
(上記画像でいう、 2番目の `www.gatsbyjs.org` と 9番目の `page-data.json` に付与されている、名前の左にある歯車アイコンは何であるのか、という質問です)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

歯車のアイコンは、それらのリクエストが **Service Worker によるもの**であることを示しています<sup>[[1]](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/#3)</sup>。

> #### What's with the gear?<sup>[[1]](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/debugging-service-workers/#3)</sup>
>
> The gear icon signifies that these requests came from the Service Worker itself. Specifically, these are the requests being made by the Service Worker's install handler to populate the offline cache.
>
> > Learn More: For a deeper understanding of the Network panel identifies Service Worker traffic take a look at this [StackOverflow discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33655173/).

また、 Service Worker によって発生した、または変更された可能性のあるリクエストは `is:service-worker-initiated` または `is:service-worker-intercepted` を用いることでフィルターすることが出来ます (後者の場合は歯車アイコンは付与されない)<sup>[[2]](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/devtools#swfilters)</sup>。

> #### Service worker filters in the Network panel<sup>[[2]](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2019/03/devtools#swfilters)</sup>
>
> Type `is:service-worker-initiated` or `is:service-worker-intercepted` in the Network panel filter text box to view requests that were caused (`initiated`) or potentially modified (`intercepted`) by a service worker.

---

gatsby.js の公式サイトでこれらを使用した場合、以下のような結果になります。

#### `is:service-worker-initiated` を使用した場合

[image: is:service-worker-initiatedを入力した例。Service Workerによって発生したリクエストがフィルターされた結果として表示されている]

#### `is:service-worker-intercepted` を使用した場合

[image: is:service-worker-interceptedを入力した例。Service Worker によって潜在的に変更されたリクエストがフィルターされた結果表示されているが、歯車アイコンは表示されていない。]